# How to load RSA Public Key from String in J2ME

Tags: java-me, public-key-encryption, encryption

I need to do some encryption in J2ME through sms. The app receives the public key in an sms as String, the same way openssl creates Public key from Private key, this is how the keys are created:

1. Private Key:   openssl genrsa -out privkey.pem 144
2. Public key:    openssl rsa -in privkey.pem -out pubkey.pem

The String is created with something like this, which is the public key:

```
MGwCAQACEwCxcz+Qk8J6CptiRg6EBpG6SHECAwEAAQISVTLKcDYhh8sTJggObTKI
pdIJAgoA7EwFr5Un3AErAgoAwD8WTwqL0vbTAgoAkuPfVPr/wD/pAgl44rKqfR0z
SRUCCgDDqC/pMSBHTJs=
```

Now, how to get to the point in a source code to get this public key in a `RSAPublicKey` ready to be used in a cipher?
To do this:

```
byte[] plaintext="some text".getBytes();
byte[] encryptedtext;
Cipher cipher=Cipher.getInstance("RSA");
RSAPublicKey pubKey=new RSAPublicKey(????????);
cipher.init(Cipher.ENCRYPT_MODE,pubkey);
cipher.doFinal(plaintext,0,plaintext.length,encryptedtext,0)
```

Comment: Do you really want to use a 144 bit modulus? This has about no security.

Comment: Also, your sequence of commands does not create a public-key file (it is actually identical to the private one).